# How to add shadow effect on bar chart using ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I'm using chartjs 3.9 to build a bar chart. I'm trying to get a shadow effect on the bars like this:

[image]

I couldn't find how to do this on the documentation. Can someone help me, please?

This are my datasets:

```
datasets: [
        {
            label: 'SLP',
            data: [23000, 46000, 40000, 41000, 39000, 25000, 45000, 40500, 41000],
            backgroundColor: gradientBg21,
            borderRadius: 9,
            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
            barPercentage: 0.8
        },
        {
            label: 'AXS',
            data: [19000, 22000, 19000, 42000, 39500, 18000, 22000, 18000, 42000],
            backgroundColor: gradientBg31,
            borderRadius: 9,
            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
            barPercentage: 0.8
        }
    ]
```

Here's my chart: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GuiRoque47/dn2Lmurt/1/)

Comment: This can't be done by default you will need to create a custom plugin for this, there is one for version 2.9 but it never got updated voe V3 so you need to do that yourself: https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-style

Answer (score -1):

```js
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Legend,
  LinearScale,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  TooltipItem,
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);

const shadowPlugin = [{
  id: 'shadow',
  beforeDraw: (chart: ChartJS<'bar', number[], unknown>) => {
    const { ctx } = chart;
    const _fill = ctx.fill;
    ctx.fill = function () {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.shadowColor = 'red';
      //ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(12,77, 229, 0.2)';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 8;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
      _fill.apply(this, arguments as any);
      ctx.restore();
    };
  },
}];

<Bar
  height={(BAR_THICKNESS + 28) * data.length + TICKS_PADDING}
  width={chartRefContainer?.current?.offsetWidth || undefined}
  ref={chartRef}
  options={options}
  data={dataWithGradient}
  plugins={shadowPlugin}
/>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKwsi.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.